# HTML5 NAV Hover Exception

Tags: html, css

I would just like a NAV bar at the top of the screen with the first list item being a non-clickable non-hover image.

I have the NAV built and hover working but I can't seem to exclude the first list item image from hover.

Is there a way to do this?

CSS:

```
nav {
   background-color: #808080;
   border: 1px solid #dedede;
   border-radius: 4px;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
   color: #888;
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 100%;
}

nav > ul > li:hover {
   background-color: rgb( 40, 44, 47 );
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a {
   color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a > .caret {
   border-top-color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
}

nav > ul > li:hover > div {
   display: block;
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
}

nav > ul > li > div ul > li:hover > a {
   background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="img\logo.png" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="products.html">Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="products.html#chair">SubMenu 1a</a></li>
                            <li><a href="products.html#table">SubMenu 1b</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">Menu 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="products.html#chair">SubMenu 2a</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="help.html">Menu 3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="products.html#chair">SubMenu 3a</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: That is too much code to plow through. Can you boil it down?

Comment: Removed CSS not related to hover.. hope that helps.  Sorry I am a noob obviously.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to remove the logo from the first `<li>` to keep your layout clean, you could use 
`nth-child` to select all the `<li>`'s individually and give those psuedo-selectors. It might add quite a bit of extra code however.

```
ul li:hover:nth-child(1) {
<!-- Leave empty if you don't want any hover effect, this would be your logo -->
cursor: default;
    }
ul li:hover:nth-child(2) {
color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 ); <! -- Add the hover effects -->

    }
ul li:hover:nth-child(3) {
color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
    }
```

And for your `a` tags.

```
ul li a:hover:nth-child(1) {
<!-- Leave empty -->
cursor: default;
}
ul li a:hover:nth-child(2) {
color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 ); <! -- Add the hover effects you want on the rest of the li's -->

    }
ul li a:hover:nth-child(3) {
color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
    }
```

Check out [how nth-child works](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) if you want to know more in-depth about its capabilities. I added `cursor: default;` just in case the cursor changed on image but normally it doesn't, just to make it not seem clickable. If this works an answer accept is appreciated.

If you want to remove the logo from the navbar entirely, then you could create a container to hold both your navbar and your logo. then float the elements depending on where you want your logo. This might not be the most efficient way to do it but it should work. You can adjust the positions with `margin` and `padding` as well. I added some other css here just for illustration.. Here is an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/kvyxLcbg/1/

Comment: Can you propose the best way to remove the logo from the nav but keep it behaving/looking like it is part of the nav?

Comment: Thanks I would like to go with nth-child.  Would you be able to show me how to achieve this using jQuery for browser compatibility?  Also what I need to do on the HTML side?  I looked at that link but am a bit lost :(

Comment: @peelers Okay so after messing around I managed to do it with jQuery for compatibility sake. Its quite a bit of extra jQuery code bit it works. Read the comments. I hope it is not too confusing. It is quite simple, all that is being done is that you select the elements with nth-child in jQuery then apply a `hover`. In jQuery you have to apply events for mouseover and mouseleave. http://jsfiddle.net/rnmore2h/1/ I hope this is an acceptable answer :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for all your work and bearing with me!  In the end I had to take the image out of the NAV due to various reasons.  Marking this correct as it answered the question posed.